# Does garbage collection work with the Go compiler (gc)?

Tags: garbage-collection, go

I noticed that garbage collection is not yet implemented in gccgo.

http://golang.org/doc/gccgo_install.html#Unimplemented

Does the standard Go compiler (gc) support garbage collection yet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

gccgo has its own runtime, the plan is to switch to use a single runtime shared by both gc and gccgo.

Also, the current garbage collector in gc is rather simple, a concurrent and much faster implementation based on research done by IBM is under development, and will probably be the one used by both gccgo and gc.

Answer (score 7):

Yes.

Comment: How did you get past the Stack Overflow length requirement? That's cool... +1.